# state of the art of subset, set containment and partial match queries

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, matching

The subset query problem is defined as:
Given a list `D` of size `N` where the entries are subsets of a universe with `m` elements, create a datastructure that detects for every query-set `Q` if there exists a set `P` in `D` so that `Q`is a subset of `P`

I was wondering what are the best known algorithms to solve this problem. I couldn't find any recent publications, just this work from 2002:
[Subset Queries](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/fb0f/9cbd3662423933ba8b91c61741a7cd06bb88.pdf)

There it is stated, that the subset query problem is equivalent to the set containment problem as well as the partial match problem.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Related: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/74833/data-structure-for-testing-all-subsets-of-a-query-for-membership/74923

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure if this is "state of the art" but take a look at this paper [Efficient subset and superset queries](http://osebje.famnit.upr.si/~savnik/drafts/settrie0.pdf).